# Problem with mdframed, listings and TikZ for a codeblock

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, luatex, mdframed

## Context

For a document I am writing, I use mdframed and listings to create a "fancy" codeblock look. I use rounded corners and custom colors for this view. During the creation of this document everything went fine until I set up mdframed (`framemethod=tikz`) for the rounded corners.

## The Problem

When the mdframed and listings environments are broken by a page, certain styling (specifically the color of line numbers and the codeblock content) is ignored or replaced by black.

## MWE and problem demonstration

Let me demonstrate the problem with a minimal example.

*Note: the filecontents of example.tex are omitted. This is a simple text file with long content.*

### MWE

Using the following code, the document (almost) looks as I need it to look without problems:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black]
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\color{white}]{example.txt}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

In the resulting PDF, the code keeps the correct color even after a pagebreak:

[image: Code color is correct even after a pagebreak splits the codeblock]

### Problem demonstration

When the necessary changes are applied to create rounded corners, the problem occurs:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt, backgroundcolor=black]
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\color{white}]{example.txt}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

In the resulting PDF, the code that continues after the pagebreak now does not have the correct color. The letters after the pagebreak should remain white and readable but here they become black and unreadable:

[image: Code color is incorrect after a pagebreak]

*The rounded corners are not visible in the limited screenshot but they are visible and applied correctly on the outer corners of the mdframed frame*

This problem seems to occur using both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

**Ideally, I would like to keep using XeLaTeX to compile my document.**

How do I solve this issue and keep the code styling persistent in codeblocks that encounter pagebreaks?

Thanks for any assistance dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the font colour in the wrong place - it should be set with `\mdfsetup{fontcolor=white}` rather than with `[basicstyle=\color{white}]`:

[image]

This was compiled with `xelatex` and `lualatex` and both output correctly:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{example.txt}
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
Text
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfsetup{fontcolor=white,roundcorner=10pt,backgroundcolor=black}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{mdframed}
    \lstinputlisting{example.txt}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

In the future, use the `filecontents` environment to create an `examples.txt` file for us please, it is minor in this case as it easy to create but it is helpful for us to have the question copy-and-paste-able so we can debug and test solutions faster.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep the use of `filecontents` in mind for the future. I can also confirm that using this solution code highlighting for the listings package keeps working. `fontcolor=white` can also be applied in a style for mdframed as an alternative for `\mdfsetup`.